# jHipster Generator for AWS not working

Tags: aws-sdk, jhipster

We have generated jHipster project using "yo jHipster" which runs fine locally.

Now, we want to deploy the application to AWS using Elastic Beanstalk.

I have tried deploying the WAR file generated for the jHipster project using the Elastic Beanstalk console, however, it fails to launch the application.

Then I came across a sub project of jHipster to generate the application for AWS directly. e.g. yo jHipster:aws

But I am getting the following error while running it. Any pointers to investigate this issue further please?

**yo jhipster:aws**
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
    at module.exports.AwsGenerator.extend.initializing.checkDatabase (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/aws/index.js:23:37)
    at Object. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/base.js:436:25)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/run-async/index.js:24:25
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/generator-jhipster/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/base.js:446:8
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:383:17)

Comment: Could you please create an issue here: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues. Then I will take a look into it.